# Matplotlib graph Legend text add or modification

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have get graph by pandas dataframe matplotlib. Legend Top there is none, none but plot text is there. how to add text there instead of none, none?

[image]

```py
df[df.Dst_Port.eq(5353)].groupby('Dst_Port'['Packet_length'].agg({'Packet':['sum','min','max','mean', 'median','std']}).plot(kind='bar',title='Destination Portwise Packets', legend=True, ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already done this add these lines of code to show legend and labels.

```
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.title('Histogram')
plt.legend()
```

Answer (score -1):

You failed to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Nevertheless, you can try the following to the end of your plotting command

```
.get_legend().set_title("Title Here")
```

Specifically, use

```
df[df.Dst_Port.eq(5353)].groupby('Dst_Port'['Packet_length'].agg({'Packet':['sum','min','max','mean', 'median','std']}).plot(kind='bar',title='Destination Portwise Packets', legend=True, ax=ax).get_legend().set_title("Title Here")
```